# Strange behavior when changing UIDeviceOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uideviceorientation

Here is what I do when I orientation changes...

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {    
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"auto_main_hor.png"]]];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    } else if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"auto_main_vert.png"]]];
    } 
}
```

When I rotate device for 180 degrees sharply I get some misdisplaying? how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'misdisplaying'?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `UIInterfaceOrientation` and `UIDeviceOrientation` are not the same thing.  You are using the device orientation where you should be using the interface orientation.